# FST_ERR_REP_ALREADY_SENT

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, fastify

So this is not a question that was something that caused me pain for days. Incase anyone is using fastify and you are trying to use a middleware with the Prehandler Option and you are getting an error like this

```
{"type":"FastifyError","message":"Reply was already sent.","stack":"FastifyError: Reply was already sent.\n    at _Reply.Reply.send (C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\eventsApp\\EventsApp\\node_modules\\fastify\\lib\\reply.js:124:26)\n    at successResponse (C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\eventsApp\\EventsApp\\src\\response\\success.js:2:24)\n    at Object.createEvent (C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\eventsApp\\EventsApp\\src\\repositories\\eventRepository.js:59:16)\n    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)\n    at async Object.newEvent (C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\eventsApp\\EventsApp\\src\\services\\eventService.js:23:21)\n    at async Object.createEvent (C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\eventsApp\\EventsApp\\src\\controllers\\eventController.js:6:22)","name":"FastifyError","code":"FST_ERR_REP_ALREADY_SENT","statusCode":500},"msg":"Reply already sent"}
```

so what you should do is that in your middleware function get rid of the `next()` fastify automatically does this for you so doing it again sends your response or request twice. And also incase if mongoDB if you are trying to send a request to create a document including the `next()` creates the record twice

Comment: I just got this error. Removing the `return` statement from my fastify.get() callback did the trick.

Comment: Thanks a lot, bro.

I was on this error for days, tried everything but nothing worked. This was lifesaving.

Answer (score 0):

[code snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HyZqB.png)

```
const date = new Date().getMilliseconds();
const filePath = `${directoryPath}/example_${date}.txt`;
const fileContent = JSON.stringify(data);

fs.writeFile(filePath, fileContent, (writeErr) => {
   if(writeErr) {
      console.error('Error writing file:', writeErr);
      // reply.code(500).send({ error: 'Internal Server Error' });
      return;
    }
    console.log("Hello filewriter")
    // reply.send({ success: true, filePath });
    return;
});
```

I removed reply, to solve this temporarily awaiting solution

Comment: Don't post code as an image. Instead, post as properly formatted text.